# How to compute slider nub to reveal contents from end to end

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm having a hard time on finding the right computation and logic to my slider.
Please see my slider here: http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/p6UVt/1/
Everything seems fine at first, but if you try to change the width value of `.item-slider-contents` to `1000px` or more, the `cache.nub` doesn't slide the `.item-slider-contents` properly. I hope you get what I mean to say. Please help me to compute this properly.
The width of `.item-slider-contents` will expand on real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I just have to add this is css:

```
div { box-sizing : border-box; position:relative; }
```

And this one should be:

```
.slider-road{
margin-top:20px;
height:10px;
width:690px;    
border:1px solid orange;    
}
```

And this is the formula:

```
var pct = (cache.nub.position().left - 2) / (cache.slider.width() - 16)
```

And whenever I change the width of `.item-slider-contents` it slides end to end properly.

Here is the updated link for reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/p6UVt/3/